# angularjs ui-router does not load JavaScript methods in nested views

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem trying to load a JavaScript method in nested views using ui-router.  I have this code:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('/', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    views: {
        '': { templateUrl:'partials/home.html'}, 

        'navbar@': { 
                templateUrl: 'includes/navbar.html'
            },
        'sidebar@': { 
                templateUrl: 'includes/sidebar.html'
            }
    } 
})
```

and in the index.php

```
<div ui-view="navbar"></div>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

the content is loaded but some methods do not work.  For example this:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});
```

If I put the sidebar and navbar code directly in the index.php, the JavaScript method works.  However, if the code is in nested view, it doesn't work.

ps: I'm using this template http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-2/

Comment: you calling it from MainCtrl ?

Comment: debug it: add a breakpoint at `metisMenu` call time and see your sidebar is not there.